# error al guardar imagen en mi servidor web con php

Tags: php

Estoy intentando crear para poder subir fotos  a mi sitio web con php pero el código que estoy usando no me muestra la imagen una vez subida a mi servidor web; no se qué podria fallar...

Este es el código que estoy usando actualmente:

```
<?php

$imagenCodificada = file_get_contents("https://i.imgur.com/FNJn8FA.png");
if(strlen($imagenCodificada) <= 0) exit("No se recibió ninguna imagen");

$imagenCodificadaLimpia = str_replace("data:image/png;base64,", "", urldecode($imagenCodificada));


$imagenDecodificada = base64_decode($imagenCodificadaLimpia);


$nombreImagenGuardada = "foto_" . uniqid() . ".png";


file_put_contents($nombreImagenGuardada, $imagenDecodificada);


exit($nombreImagenGuardada);
?>
```

Aparece la imagen en blanco

Cómo podria subir la imagen sin que aparezca en blanco?

Muchas gracias antemano!

Comment: Tengo la leve (gran) sospecha de que la imagen se daña cuando la codificas a BASE64 usando [urldecode()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.urldecode.php) y tratando de "reconstruir" después. ¿Puedo preguntar por qué haces ese proceso? (Lo siento... ya pregunté)

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya lo repare